# Regression line lost after factor conversion

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following plot, `time` is on the x-axis but tick marks do not show for every year:

```
ggplot(mm, aes(x = time, y = value)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = variable)) + 
    geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", alpha = 0.5) + 
    facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
    theme(legend.position="none") + 
    coord_fixed(ratio = 10)
```

[image]

In order to fix this, I have converted the `time` variable to a factor, which works but then the linear regression disappears:

```
ggplot(mm, aes(x = factor(time), y = value)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = variable)) + 
    geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", alpha = 0.5) + 
    facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    coord_fixed(ratio = 10)
```

[image]

Is there a workaround for this with `geom_line`?

Comment: Just set the breaks in `scale_x_continuous` instead.

Comment: Or convert the x-axis to posixct and format the label to only show the year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `scale_x_date` is what you are looking for.

First, some reproducible data:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    y = 99:117
    , x = seq(as.Date("1999-01-01")
              , as.Date("2017-01-01")
              , "year")
  )
```

Then, this is the way you can set to some "pretty" break points while still getting a tick at each year. If you want every year labelled, then use `date_breaks = "1 year"` instead of the `breaks` and `date_minor_breaks` arguments I have now

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y) ) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = pretty(df$x)
               , date_minor_breaks = "1 year"
               , date_labels = "%Y")
```

gives

[image]

Or, if your years are just numeric (and not dates), you can use `scale_x_continuous` for a similar effect:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    y = 99:117
    , x = 1999:2017
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y) ) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(df$x)
                     , minor_breaks = unique(df$x)) +
  theme_gray()
```

Gives a plot that is indistinguishable from above.